# Can i create lists of lists using Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, many-to-many

i am using Core Data in an iOS app i am writing

i have an entity called Track and an entity called List

a List comprises a number of Tracks, but can also include other Lists.

to give an analogy, imagine a playlist comprising a combination of songs and other playlists, which themselves can have both songs and other playlists in them.

the xdatamodeld seems to accommodate having a list entity with a name attribute and to-many relationships to both tracks and lists, but i'm wondering if this is the right way to do this.  i thought i'd ask the experienced programmers here what if any problems i may have to look out for if i go this route...i assume there is a significant risk of circular references, and that a list should not contain any lists that contain it...but there may be other problems as well...

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach.  Just be careful when setting what happens to dependents in the event of record deletion to avoid circular deletion.  A cleaner way would be to create a listItem table that contains a boolean field to indicate whether the item is associated to list or track, then have has_one relationship with list and track.  List table will contain listItems and listItems will manage what it contains.  It's same as yours except it adds a design separation that makes it easy to deal with dependencies.